# Panel regression in SAS using subgroups in data set

Tags: sas, regression

Below is a sample of my dataset:
[image]

Within in the variable "Country" I have countries belonging to Group A, and Group B (dummy variables).

I want to do a panel regression in SAS on the returns of these countries as such:

> model Returns = Event(0,1)

with the added condition that, for example,

I only want to consider countries belonging to Group A, and during a Pre-2000 period.

Is there a way to code that in SAS using this current dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS/ETS provides the `proc panel` procedure that will model panel data. Note that you must have identical time periods for each cross-section. If you don't, you'll need to prepare the data with `proc timeseries` or `proc expand` beforehand.

Once you read your data in, you'll use `proc panel` with a `where` statement to construct the model.  The `ID` statement is a bit different in `proc panel`. It first expects the cross-section variable, then the time ID variable.

```
proc panel data=have;
    where GroupA = 1
          AND year(date) < 2000;

    id country date;
    class event;

    model Returns = Event;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for this Stu! I know it's outside the scope of my question, but i was wondering - would there be any fundamental difference/advantage or disadvantage in using your regression as opposed to say the following:


proc panel data=have; 
        id country date;
        model Returns = groupA Event Pre-2000;
    run;
?

Furthermore, What exactly is the function of the CLASS statement here? I've had a look at the guidebook, but couldn't understand it's contextual relevance.

Comment: If you did include Pre-2000 as a variable, you would not be filtering your data. Instead, you will be creating a parameter estimate for pre-2000 data that, essentially, is determining an average "adjustment factor" for these events if it's pre or post year 2000. This might be useful depending on what type of model that you need.  The Class statement tells SAS that a variable is either binary or a categorical. You do not necessarily need it here since binary variables only take 2 values, but it's good practice to do so. It can also make reading the parameter estimates a bit easier.